# Does Facebook Home uninstall cleanly?

Tags: uninstallation, facebook-home

I am hardly a regular Facebook user, but am curious about Facebook Home – mostly curiosity about its design and implementation.

I have a Nexus 7 running Jelly Bean 4.2.2. If I were to install it, can I be confident that uninstalling it will leave everything (home screens, etc) as it was?

Comment: Are you rooted? What launcher do you use? Backup your data first, ensure your launcher has its settings backed up as well, no harm in doing so, then install the FB launcher, if you don't like it, restore from backup including launcher settings.

Comment: It is, at its core, just a launcher. Except for possibly leaving some files behind it shouldn't mess anything up.